# Get a still frame during webcam video capture on Linux

Tags: python, linux, video, ffmpeg

I want to capture video from a webcam (saving to file), while occasionally getting the most recent still frame (from python code). **Is there a way to do this on Linux?**

**What I've Tried:**

```
# Capture Video:
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1024x576 -i /dev/video0 myvideo.mp4
```

...

```
# In another terminal, try to capture the latest still frame:
ffmpeg -sseof -3 -i myvideo.mp4 -update 1 -q:v 1 current_frame.jpg
```

But, I get varied responses from this last command, such as

```
Cannot use -sseof, duration of myvideo.mp4 not known
```

and

```
[matroska,webm @ 0x55e1aae26900] Duplicate element
    Last message repeated 2 times
```

**Additional Notes/Constraints:**

1. It must be possible to control the solution from python (e.g. calling `ffmpeg` via `subprocess.Popen`) to (a) start recording, (b) get frames at arbitrary points, (c) stop recording.
2. Frame timing doesn't have to be exact. A frame within the last couple seconds is fine.
3. Any container format is fine (mkv, mp4, etc.)
4. Other programs are fine, not just `ffmpeg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple outputs for FFmpeg.  Combine your commands:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 1024x576 -i /dev/video0 myvideo.mp4 -r 1 -update 1 current_frame.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks! That does the trick @Brad, and I am happy to poll for the latest current_frame.jpg file.